# Apache Solr - Indexing ZIP files

Tags: java, solr, lucene, extract, apache-tika

My web app is an e-mail service. It stores email messages in MySQL database and email attachments are on a disk.

The database is similar to:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | sender | receiver | subject | body | attach_dir | attachments |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 444    | 555      | Apples  | Hey! | /mnt/emails| att1.doc\r\n|
|    |        |          |         |      |            | att2.doc\r\n|
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 77     | 22       | Pears   | Hola!| /mnt/emails| att1.zip\r\n|
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I index it with the following data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="mysql"
            type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/email?
              useUnicode=true&#038;
              characterEncoding=UTF-8&#038;
              useTimezone=true&#038;
              serverTimezone=UTC"
            user="user" 
            password="pass"/>

<dataSource name="files"
            type="BinFileDataSource" />
<document>
  <entity name="email" dataSource="mysql"
    query="SELECT id, subject, body, date, attach, attach_dir FROM email"
    transformer="RegexTransformer"
   >
     <field column="id" name="id"/>
     <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
     <field column="body" name="content"/>
     <field column="date" name="last_modified"/>
     <field column="attach" name="attach" splitBy="\r\n" />
     <field column="attach_dir" name="attach_dir"/>
     <entity name="attach_glob" dataSource="null" 
     processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
     baseDir="/mnt/attach/${email.attach_dir}" fileName=".*" 
     recursive="false" onError="skip">
         <entity name="email_attachment" dataSource="files" 
         processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
         url="${attach_glob.fileAbsolutePath}">
             <field column="text" name="attach_content"/>
         </entity>
     </entity>         
  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

This is working good with all the files except compressed files such as `.zip`. For `.zip` files the `attach_content` field gets filled only with the file names from the zip archive instead of content of the extracted files from the zip archives.

However if I use `SimplePostTool` like this:

```
/opt/solr/bin/post -c mycollection /mnt/attach/message3/att1.zip
```

then I get all content extracted from all the files inside of the zip archive and this is what I need. But I would need this content to be part of the documents added by Data Import Handler with the data-config.xml above.

Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming you are on a modern Solr version, with a modern Tika version, you'll need to set extractEmbedded to true on the TikaEntityProcessor configuration for it to parse embedded documents.

Comment: @DaveMeikle Thank you for the right thing. I’m also thinking to switch to SolrJ as DIH seems to be getting out of support soon.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's scheduled for removal in 9.0. There is a package you can use [here](https://github.com/rohitbemax/dataimporthandler) but SolJ is a good route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need need to set *extractEmbedded* to *true* on the TikaEntityProcessor configuration for it to set the appropriate Parser in the Apache Tika *ParseContext* for it to parse embedded documents.

For example, you can change you configuration from the question to have this set like the below:

```
 <entity name="email_attachment" dataSource="files" 
     processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
     url="${attach_glob.fileAbsolutePath}" extractEmbedded="true">
         <field column="text" name="attach_content"/>
  </entity>
```

See [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-tikaentityprocessor) for more details.