# Replacing "\n" with actual new lines as part of [ find ... -exec ... sed ] construction

Tags: bash, sed, solr, apache-tika

To make [the long story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342408/apache-solr-indexing-zip-files) short I use `Apache Tika` bash script (in my case this is `/opt/solr/bin/post`) to extract content of `.zip` files and store that content as text for further indexing.

So as result I have to parse `.txt` files similar to below:

```
java -classpath /opt/solr/dist/solr-core-8.7.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dout=yes -Dparams=literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text&defaultField=text -Dc=mycoll -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool ./архив 1.zip
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/mycoll/update?literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text&defaultField=text...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file архив 1.zip (application/octet-stream) to [base]/extract
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":361},
  "":"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n05-12-2020 Lorem IP (?㫥??????? ??ਭ?).docx\nLorrer I/P\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t05-12-2020\n\nNia: GE Rudoge\n\n---------------------------------\n\nТа. К/П Арпрот керем\n\n\n\nUp: Пренорас Караб.\n\n\n\nКротанил Кераминд,\n\nИ аттаче фуеле редирю \n\n\n\nС УВ, Джекпо\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
  "null_metadata":[
    "stream_size",["11436"],
    "X-Parsed-By",["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser"],
    "stream_content_type",["application/octet-stream"],
    "resourceName",["/mnt/remote/users/zhilov/!tmp/./архив 1.zip"],
    "Content-Type",["application/zip"]]}
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/mycoll/update?literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text&defaultField=text...
Time spent: 0:00:00.668
```

Those files are produced with the following command:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
/opt/solr/bin/post -c mycoll "$f" -out yes -params \
"literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text \
&defaultField=text"  > "$f.txt"; \
sed -i -n "/QTime/{N;s/.*\n.*:.//;s/.,$//p;}" "$f.txt"' \;
```

The last part of the command extracts the real final text which I need:

> \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n05-12-2020 Lorem IP (?㫥???????
> ??ਭ?).docx\nLorrer I/P\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t05-12-2020\n\nNia:
> GE Rudoge\n\n---------------------------------\n\nТа. К/П Арпрот
> керем\n\n\n\nUp: Пренорас Караб.\n\n\n\nКротанил Кераминд,\n\nИ аттаче
> фуеле редирю \n\n\n\nС УВ, Джекпо\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n

For some reason during all that conversion all the new lines got in the text as `\n` stings. To fix that I'm trying to convert `\n` back to actual `new lines` with:

`sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`

So my full final command is:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
/opt/solr/bin/post -c mycoll "$f" -out yes -params \
"literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text \
&defaultField=text"  > "$f.txt"; \
sed -i -n "/QTime/{N;s/.*\n.*:.//;s/.,$//p;}" "$f.txt"; \
sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' "$f.txt"' \;
```

But with that '\n' gets replaced as stings again so no `new lines` are added. I feel the problem here are quotes. But I can't figure out what it is exactly. What can be a problem here?

**UPD:** I have just realized I have to replace all the [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) in the text, such as `\n`, `\t` etc. But at least `\n`, so any answer would be a great of help.

Comment: How abour echo -e "$(<file.txt)"

Comment: @markp-fuso my last sed command `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' file"` words as a separate command but not as part of the whole `find ... -exec` thing

Comment: @RamanSailopal thank you. It works as a separate command. Then I tried as part of the whole thing: `find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
/opt/solr/bin/post -c mycoll "$f" -out yes -params \
"literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text \
&defaultField=text"  > "$f.txt"; \
sed -i -n "/QTime/{N;s/.*\n.*:.//;s/.,$//p;}" "$f.txt"; \
echo -e "$(<$f.txt)"' \;` and it gives me just `-e` as output instead of the extracted text

Comment: this fails to replace the characters: `-exec sh -c 'sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' {}' \;` but if I switch to double quotes and escape the first backslash with another backslash: `-exec sh -c 'sed -i "s/\\\n/\n/g" {}' \;` then the characters are replaced (on my system); I'm sure there's a straight forwar(ish) explanation for the quoting and escaping, but don't ask me (at this time) ...

Comment: @markp-fuso Great, that worked! Would you suggest in your answer handling the rest of control characters such as `\t` in the same command?

Comment: I'm leaning towards 'yes, use the same approach for other control characters' but, of course, test and verity

Comment: @RamanSailopal `echo "$(cat "$f.txt")"` worked perfectly for me